# Why InsertionSort doesn't run?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

This is the code of InsertionSort but why it doesn't run? That is, it does not sort the numbers in ascending order.

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int [] n = {3,2,1};

    for (int j = 2; j < n.length; j++) {        
        int key = n[j];
        int i = j - 1;  

        while (i > 0 && n[i] > key) {           
            n[i + 1] = n[i];
            i = i-1;            
        }   

        n[i + 1] = key;     
    }   

    for(int k: n)
        System.out.print(k);        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Time to use a debugger.

Comment: is the insertionsort present on the algorithms book in pseudocode, what does the debugger have to do with it?

Comment: The debugger has everything to do with it. What do you think we do when we try to help figure out problems with your code? Stare at it and hope we have a Eureka moment? Run the code in our minds? We all just cook with water. We paste your code into our favorite IDE and run it with a debugger to see what's going on. And you can do the same. I strongly recommend you learn how (and when) to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your indexing you have considered for your algorithm is 1 based. it needs to be zero based (thats how it is for arrays).

in your for loop start from j =1

```
for (int j = 1; j < n.length; j++)
```

and in your while loop check for `while(i>=0 && n[i])>key)`

Answer (score 1):

You should start your `for` loop at `1`:

```
for (int j = 1; j < n.length; j++) {
```

and your while loop should be `>= 0`:

```
while (i >= 0 && n[i] > key) {
```

which gives:

> 123